# Como criar botão no React Native que redireciona para uma pagina de rede social

Tags: react-native

Preciso criar botões de rede socias dentro do meu app pra fazer o redirecionamento pra pagina em questão.

Exemplo:

Clicando no botão do icone do facebook eu vou parar na página em questão através da URL abrindo o navegador ou o app do facebook.

Comment: Tenta dar uma olhada nesse cara aqui: https://reactnative.dev/docs/linking

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Você pode usar o método nativo **Linking** do React Native!

Exemplo:

```
import { Linking, ToastAndroid } from 'react-native'

const openUrl = async(url) => {
  if(await Linking.canOpenURL(url)) {
    await Linking.openURL(url)
  }
  else {
    ToastAndroid.show('Can\'t open this URL', ToastAndroid.SHORT)
  }
}
```

Agora é só implementar essa função dentro da função `onPress` do botão, passando o link que você deseja como argumento.